I use VS Code, how can I smoothly migrate from ASP.NET Core in .NET 7 to .NET 8？
I am currently using VS Code for C# code debugging. I am currently using .NET 7.0 and I want to upgrade to .NET 8.0. I found the following Microsoft documentation webpage, but I have some questions about the content and I don't know how to proceed.

The webpage says, "Update the .NET SDK version in global.json", but it doesn't mention where this file is located. When I enter dotnet --info in CMD, the output shows:
Environment variables: Not set
global.json file: Not found

I asked gpt, and it said: "If there is no global.json file in the project root directory, you can manually create one.".
The problem is, I have many solutions. Do I have to create a new global.json file for each project? That seems like a lot of work!

The webpage also says, "Update the target framework. Update the project file's Target Framework Moniker (TFM) to net8.0."
My understanding of this statement is to update the .csproj file. But each solution has many .csproj files. Do I have to update all of them?
Gpt's answer is, "Indeed, for solutions that contain multiple projects, manually updating each project's .csproj file can be a lot of work. However, you can reduce the manual work by writing a script to update these files in bulk. Here are a few solutions that can help simplify this process." I'm not entirely confident in gpt's answer.


I have many questions and uncertainties in the upgrade process mentioned above. Is there any specific guidance or a simpler upgrade method? Or is there a video tutorial with detailed upgrade steps? If I completely uninstall the current 7.0 version and reinstall the 8.0 version, will it render all my current projects unusable? Or do I still need to manually update each solution and project file in VS Code?
LogAn.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

LogAnalyzerTest.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LogAn\LogAn.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


The question is unclear. The editor you use to edit your source files has no effect on the contents of those files. You don't need global.json to upgrade to .NET 8. Mentioning statistical text generators in a question about upgrading .NET versions, something that's very well documented in both the .NET team's blogs and the official documentation, doesn't explain what your actual problem is

And yes, you do need to change the version in all csproj files. That's where each project's target version is stored, not global.json.

You don't need global.json to upgrade to .NET 8.-----But which page will prompt for an upgrade? May I ask what is the reason for this?

And yes, you do need to change the version in all csproj files.-----If I uninstall .Net7 first, and then install .Net8. Finally, I build all solutions again. Can this avoid manually changing all csproj files?

No, you don't need to uninstall .NET 7. It's not manual work to just do a File Replace on *.csproj and change net7.0 to net8.0. what is the reason because that's all that's needed? I suspect the real problem here are the assumptions that you need to make manual changes, not actual problems you encountered. You're reading the docs expecting them to talk about manual changes and tools to handle them and don't realize there's no need for a tool

Besides, you can mix targets in the same solution. Your main project can target .NET 8 and still use projects that are still at .NET 6. If you really have a large project you may want to perform a rolling upgrade, fixing possible issues. one project at a time.

I assume you have SDK installed for 8.0.
As you know each project defines its own target framework version. It is easier to develop solution where all projects share same framework version but I've seen cases where that goal is hard to reach.
How to update your framework version is quite simple. You need to open your project .csproj file and update its TargetFramework to version 8. Like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...

As GPT said changing multiple projects to .net core 8.0 version it might be a lot of work. Also note that it is recommended to update some related libraries to later versions as well. For example EntityFramework Core from 7 to 8 if that ORM is used.
You could improve your question by stating what is the actual need for updating .NET Core version? Is there a dependant library? How many projects would you like to upgrade?
What is your project structure and/or how does your .csproj file look like at the moment.

I'll add that chatGPT is right when it says you can use a script to automate this. And with Notepad++, you can search and replace <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework> by <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> in a folder.

Remember to search and replace for related libraries as well like that EF Core.

Thank you for your answer, I have added several code examples in the original question.
What you mentioned, "Is there a dependent library? How many projects would you like to upgrade?" is exactly what I am concerned about. My current project results are relatively simple. I can also manually update these files. But for enterprise users, their projects are large and complex. There are many dependencies between projects. It seems unrealistic to update them manually. Does Microsoft not provide some tools to replace manual work?

@bokabokaboka what manual work? It's just a File Replace for all *.csproj files from "net7.0"to"net8.0"`, and a package upgrade.

@KettuJKL it's not a lot of work to just replace net7.0 with net8.0 in the File Replace dialog. The actual work is handling the breaking changes after upgrading packages.

I agree. Actual work is going through breaking changes if there are any. I've had projects that didn't have any breaking changes when net version was upgraded and on the other hand sometimes code has broken.
